# Assign in Mat with OpenCV

Tags: opencv, mat

I need assign values in M (a variable type Mat) with values CV_32FC1 (float), but is long time at size of  10000x10000. i.e:

```
 for (i=0 ; i<rows; i++)   
   for (j=0 ; j<cols; j++){
      ...build variable NEW_VALUE for indexes i, j
      M.at<float>(i,j) = NEW_VALUE   
   }
```

the code above required 1 second aprox. Other form I see, is defining a union (copy bytes):

```
typedef union{float _float;  uchar _uchar[4];} Bits;
...
Bits bits;
float new_value;
for (i=0 ; i<rows; i++)
  for (j=0 ; j<cols; j+=4){
     ...//build variable new_value for indexes i, j
     bits._float = new_value;
     M.data[i*cols + j] = bits._uchar[0];
     M.data[i*cols + j+1] = bits._uchar[1];
     M.data[i*cols + j+2] = bits._uchar[3];
     M.data[i*cols + j+3] = bits._uchar[3];
  }
```

That is much faster that first. But not working. I tried doing:

```
 memcpy(&M.data[i*cols + j], bits._uchar[0], 1);
 memcpy(&M.data[i*cols + j+1], bits._uchar[1], 1);
 ...
```

But not working.

And:

```
 memcpy(&M.at<float>(i,j), bits._uchar, 4);
```

is very slow also.

I need to know how to copy the bytes of the new_value correctly within of M

Answer (score 1):

Your code is slow because you are performing a lot of calculations for each pixel. Multiplication operation is not a cheap operation and you use it multiple times either explicitly (i*cols + j) or implicitly (at< float>(i,j)). Read [this tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html#howtoscanimagesopencv) for better understanding of how pixels can be accessed efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
float *prtM=(float*)M.data;
for (i=0 ; i<rows; i++)   
   for (j=0 ; j<cols; j++){
       //...build variable NEW_VALUE for indexes i, j
       *prtM = NEW_VALUE;
       prtM++;
   }
```

Comment: you are setting NEW_VALUE to the pointer, not to the data it points to.

Comment: ups,I missed the * over there, thanks @MichaelBurdinov

Comment: You are welcome. Note however that this approach works only for the images that are continuous in memory, i.e. your image is not ROI of some bigger image. To fix this you can use 'float *prtM = M.ptr<float>(i);' for each row.

Answer (score 0):

```
float* p;
for (i=0 ; i<rows; i++)  
{
    p = M.ptr<float>(i);
    for (j=0 ; j<cols; j++)
    {
        *p++ = NEW_VALUE;
    }
}
```

paghdv's code is the best optimized one, but will not work if the values int the matrix is not continuous.